# Permission request screen on android with App Engine backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, authorization, google-play-services

I am using app engine as backend for an android app. I want users of my app to authenticate with their google accounts and on the backend, I use the [users service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/)  to access the user details.This approach is described [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app). The very first time user installs the android app, he gets a screen like the one shown below. The screen displays user's email, android app name (both redacted) and my app engine app shows up as "Google App Engine". Is there a way to customize this name? Because it can be very confusing to the user as they would not know what "Google App Engine" is.

[image: Screen shown first time user tries to get authentication token]

Comment: I just found this question looking for an answer to what this permission does on one of the app I just installed.. So yes; this permission is kinda confusing.